# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, selenium

I am running following conftest.py code, but getting error UnboundLocalError: local variable 'driver' referenced before assignment

also setup() function is passed as parameter in test_login.py file to run driver there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def setup(browser):

    if browser == 'chrome':
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Drivers/chromedriver.exe")
        # print("Launching Chrome Browser.....")
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:/Drivers/geckodriver.exe")
        # print("Launching Firefox Browser.....")
    return driver

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser")

@pytest.fixture()
def browser(request):
    request.config.getoption("--browser")
```

Comment: What if both conditions in `if` and `elif` are not met? Then `driver` is never initialised. In other words, what if the browser is neither chrome nor ff?

Comment: Did you try to define `pytest_addoption` and `browser` before `setup`?

Comment: now i am not facing error, but browser is not picking the browser which i give in command line